# Possible to have an Android VM I created communicate to a mobile network with a valid SIM?

Tags: android, sms, emulation

I have a stack of working SIMs (400 to be exact). I currently have an android 2.2 emulator that can mimic the IMEI and SIMSerial No. from the real SIM. I'm currently working on porting this emulator to a virtual machine that could run in XenCenter. I've played around with several scripts that can forward messages and reply back through the emulator via telnet. But it's all emulated. I need the mobile network to mistake these VMs as actual physical phones. The idea is to get rid of the 400+ physical phones we have and virtualize them.

My question is this: Is it possible to get an instance of a phone emulator to be able to send and receive SMS messages if I have valid SIMs? For example emulate GSM over ethernet or even connect the VM to a virtual appliance that's connected to a physical GSM modem. So if this physical phone has the phone number 555-555-4444, I could get rid of the physical phone and replace  it with a virtual one. Texting 555-555-4444 will cause the VM to receive the message. Is this even possible? I'm thinking it might be beyond me. The only way I could think of doing it is bridging the VM to a physical GSM modem or SMS gateway with an emulator that can fake having a real SIM in it.

Thoughts? Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

There will be lot more parameters on a SIM than just IMEI and SIMSerial. These need to be directly read by the modem.

Phone emulator cannot send sms to live network. The GSM network protocol stack is not present on Android.

As far as bridging the VM to physical GSM modem is concerned again you will need individual GSM modem which should read SIM. Android does not have even sim reading capabilities.

Comment: (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻   that is what I figured. Thanks for the information. So I guess the only real way to improve would be to go the SMS aggregate route. Thanks :)